# Python chat reading and writing simultaneously

Tags: python

I am trying to build a client side chat which can send and read messages simultaneously.

One problem is that when I write a message, if someone else sends something its disrupt the message I am writing.

Another problem is the raw_input which blocks the user from reading new messages.
I tried to fix this problem by using msvcrt which causes another problem (I cant see the message I am writing and edit it).

How can I fix those 3 problem?

===>edit: Without using threads.

Comment: Is threading an option?  Can you post (at least part) of what you have to give some context?

Comment: without threads, and I don't have much code writen since I am trying to plan how to do everything first.

Comment: Planning ahead is the best way.  Personally, I prefer asynchronous to threading...easier to debug...usually harder to break.  I'm not a huge fan of twisted...but I like to build a lot myself...but others swear by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need asynchronous sockets...that will give you ability to handle sending and receiving in a single thread.

Look here for [asynchronous sockets in python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/asyncore.html).  This will let you code it "bare bones" (i.e. keep most of your code and just use the sockets).

Another option is to use [Twisted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_%28software%29).  This has some complications, it is a complete framework, but it gives you a lot of lift.

You can also try multi-threading.  This is **not** trivial to do, however.

Comment: Can you give me a simple example of using asynchronous sockets?

Comment: Take a look at the bottom of the asynchronous python sockets page.  You will want to use loop() but give it an argument so it only goes a few times and then your main program can do whatever else it needs to do (e.g. update UI, etc.).  I haven't done one of these for a while, so no working examples at hand...but google seems to have a few...